# Detecting Click outside a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a submit button and a text field. I know how to detect when user clicks inside the text field. Basically what i am doing is, when user clicks inside the text field, hide the text.

```js
if (submitTextArea.addEventListener) {
  submitTextArea.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (submitTextArea.value == 'Enter First Name') { //Customize this text string to whatever you want
      submitTextArea.value = '';
    }
  });
}
```

Now when user clicks away from the text field, that is in some other area out side the text field i want to restore the text.

How can i detect the click outside text field?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement a placeholder.  Use it instead of what you are trying to do.  If you need to support older browsers apply a polyfill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What you looking for is a `blur` event.**

```
submitTextArea.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  // code here
});
```

---

> Here you have a entire page of `JavaScript` events with supported browsers : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

---

**Also it would be better if you use `focus` and `blur` events for this task, so that `click` event may be used for another action.**

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/6nspgrj4/2/

Code:

```
submitTextArea.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    submitTextArea.value = 'Got focus';
});

submitTextArea.addEventListener("blur", function () {
    submitTextArea.value = 'Lost focus';
});
```

Comment: What kind of `input` field are you working on? What is the browser you work on? Are you using any frameworks `jQuery` etc?

Comment: Not Working in IE